# How to remove excess brackets in a 3d list to make a 2d list?

Tags: python, list

I am doing a leetcode problem named [3Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/): Here is my code:

```py
class Solution:
    def threeSum(self, nums: List[int]) -> List[List[int]]:
        def twoSum(nums, target):
            d = {
                target - nums[0]: 0 
            }

            for i in range(1, len(nums)):
                if nums[i] in d:
                    return [nums[i], target - nums[i]]
                else:
                    d[target-nums[i]] = i
        arr = []

        for i in range(len(nums)):
            s = twoSum(nums[i+1:] + nums[:i], -nums[i])
            if s == None:
                continue
            if s not in arr:
                arr.append(s)
                arr[len(arr) - 1].append(nums[i])
        
        n = list(map(sorted, arr))
        print(n)
        res = []
        [res.append(x) for x in n if x not in res]
        return res
```

It isn't the greatest of solutions, but I ran into a problem. I noticed that I couldn't just implement my 2Sum solution into it because, to put it simply, while the 2Sum problem guarantees that there is only one solution, there could be many solutions for 3Sum. Therefore, I thought instead of just returning one list, how about a return a 2d list, so that the outer list can hold the many solutions.

However, that raised another problem, the one I hope the answer to this problem will solve. I'm then appending that 2Sum into the `arr` list. In doing so, `arr` becomes a 3d list, which I would like to be a 2d list.

I am wondering how to make a list like this: `arr = [[[3, 2, 9, 4], [1, 9, 5]], [3, 2, 2]]` into a list like this: `arr = [[3, 2, 9, 4], [1, 9 ,5], [3, 2, 2]]`, so that it meets the problem requirements. In other words, how to remove only the brackets that make the list a 3d list so that it becomes a 2d list. The data type of `arr` is a list.

Notice1: I understand that in the problem, the subarrays of `arr` would only have 3 elements each, but I would like to generalize it so that the answer to this question isn't specific to only this leetcode problem.

Notice2: I want `[[3, 2, 9, 4], [1, 9 ,5], [3, 2, 2]]` instead of `[[3, 2, 9, 4, 1, 9 ,5], [3, 2, 2]]`, because the second list also removes some brackets of the 2d lists. Hope that makes sense.

Another example is `arr` being equal to `[[[5]], [3, 2, 3, 5, 10]]`. If it were that case, I would like to make it `[[5], [3, 2, 3, 5, 10]]`, so that it is only a 2d array.

One last example is `[[[2, 6, 3, 1, 9], [3, 1, 99, 4]], [[4, 15], [4, 7, 2, 1]]]`. That would turn into `[[2, 6, 3, 1, 9], [3, 1, 99, 4], [4, 15], [4, 7, 2, 1]]`.

Thank you!

Comment: The correct answer here depends on what your data is, so please remember to [edit] your post [to explain](/help/how-to-ask) what these lists are/what they represent.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand. Do you just want me to give variable names to the lists?

Comment: Can you be more accurate with what the lists represent?
Is it has to be always 3 integers? do you have more similar cases the code should handle?

Comment: I wanted you to explain what kind of data this is supposed to be, so that we can recommend the correct approach. If it's image data, or it represents an computation matrix, then you might want an `ndarray`, which is a completely different answer from if it's just meaningless numbers you need to iterate over, in which case list flattening will work just fine. So: what are you using these lists for, what do they represent?

Comment: Why shouldn't the result be `[[3, 2, 9, 4, 1, 9 ,5], [3, 2, 2]]`? How do we know *which* "brackets to remove"?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry, I'm not very good at coding so I don't really understand. As far as I'm concerned, the type of data this is is a list. I'm trying to use this technique on a leetcode problem I'm trying to solve. Thank you! I'll try to improve my question.

Comment: @KellyBundy Good point, I'll elaborate

Comment: If this is a leetcode exercise, remember to actually explain what the exercise is, because this isn't really about programming so much as about being able to describe what you're trying to do: if you don't know what the data is, then it's virtually guaranteed that this is not something "you need to do", so explain what you're doing =) And if that means going "I'm working on a homework problem" or "I'm doing a leetcode exercise", that's fine but then mention that's what you're doing in your post and give the actual exercise.

Comment: It's this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/3sum/ My code is too long to be shown here. I'll write it in the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loop over the list. If an element is a 2d list, extend the result to flatten it, otherwise append the element onto the result.

```
data = [[[3, 2, 9], [1, 9, 5]], [3, 2, 2]]
result = []
for i in data:
    if isinstance(i[0], list):
        result.extend(i)
    else:
        result.append(i)

print(result)
```